# No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode

I am getting this error and can not figure out why.  All my other routes work in local and remote when I open in browser but users.  I am totally new to ruby and Xcode

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you need to also specify the `:index` action when defining the users routes:

```html
ParkApp::Application.routes.draw do

  
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :update] do
        collection do
          match '/me', to: 'users#show', via: :get
        end
      end
      ## Needed to allow cross origin request from webapp
      match '/users/:id', to: 'users#update', via: :post
      resources :sweetches, only: [:create, :update, :index]
      match '/sweetches/:id', to: 'sweetches#update', via: :post
      # Get the messages to display on the views
      match '/message_views', to: 'message_views#index', as: :message_views, via: :get
      resources :posts

    end
  end
  match '/admin', to: 'admin#index', via: :get
  match '/admin', to: 'admin#create', via: :post
  match '/admin/:id', to: 'admin#destroy', as: :delete_fake, via: :delete

end
```

This should make the route you are trying to follow valid. If you take a look at the last snippet in your question you will see that the `api/v1/users` GET route isn't defined, my change to your routes will fix that.

Comment: i get this error with your answer: Unknown action
The action 'index' could not be found for API::V1::UsersController

Comment: You will need to also have an `index` method defined in your `API::V1::UsersController`.

Comment: can you give me an example of what I should put please?

Comment: please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because, as the error says, your application does not have a route that matches "/users".

See `api_v1_users_path  POST    /api/v1/users(.:format) api/v1/users#create` in your post. This means that the POST request to path `/api/v1/users` invokes the create method of your API::V1::UsersController. So send request to `/api/v1/users`, but not to '/users`.

I've never used Objective-C, but I guess you need to replace `NSString stringWithFormat:@"/users"` with `NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/v1/users"`.

Note that you need to send a POST request. Opening the above path in browser sends a GET request to your application, resulting in 404 not found error.

Comment: the app is sending a post request and get 404 in debug area.  I changed it to /api/vi/users with same error.  I am missing a route somewhere.

Comment: `/api/vi/users` is a typo. It should be `/api/v1/users`. My bad. I edited my answer.

Comment: I put it with correct wording but still same error.  Its something to do with my routes

Comment: Assuming that your routes do have `api_v1_users_path  POST /api/v1/users(.:format) api/v1/users#create`, it's probably the request (client) that is causing the error. Are you sure you are sending POST request? The error message in the title of your question says that the app received a GET request, not POST. I've never used Objective-C but your code snippet does not seem to set HTTP method to POST either. Have you tried sending POST request using curl? If you have, can you share the exact command you used?

Comment: but when I try get request on local or remote I get same error about no route for user

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. You get the error because your app doesn't have a route for GET request to `/api/v1/users`. You need to send POST request.